# Problem with kef x300a speakers

Tags: usb, pulseaudio, alsa

I've tried to make my kef x300a speakers work on ubuntu, but with little success so far.

When connecting with usb I get a lot of errors in syslog like:
[Error opening PCM device front:1: No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrULn.png)

The usb soundcard pops up and disappears constantly in pavucontrol. It's possible to play sound when this happens, but it's interrupted every time the usb device is reset by system.

I get this output from lsusb: [lsusb-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpFu.png)

I've also tried to use the soundcard on ubuntu 21.10 in virtualbox, and it works.

[lsusb -t on virtualbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGWdW.png)

[syslog from virtualbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Vow.png)

When using the soundcard on virtualbox the usbfs driver is used on the host computer. When disconnecting the soundcard from virtualbox the host computer switch driver to snd-usb-audio, and yields a bunch of errors.

Anyone who know how to fix this issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like KEF has moved to Yamaha dac in revision with usb id 27ac:1002.

I managed to get the device work by adding quirk for the Yamaha MOX6/MOX8 soundcard.

```
rmmod snd-usb-audio # make sure all usb soundcards are unplugged when doing this

modprobe snd-usb-audio quirk_alias=27ac1002:04991503
```

Then plug in the speaker, unplug it, and plug it in again. Workaround is not perfect as the driver fail the first time device is plugged in.

If anyone know a better solution a comment would be great! :)